# SQL join query with conditions

Tags: mysql

[Table IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHOcw.png) I'm a beginner in SQL and need help with the below pls. I need to compare table1 and table2 and display matching IDs as output if present in both tables. If not present in table 2 should display null. Output should display values for one single day and version. Thanks in advance

```
Table 1

|ID |TDate      |Tversion|
 :-  :---------  :------- 
|1  |05-03-2022 |0.1     | 
|1  |05-03-2022 |0.2     |
|1  |04-03-2022 |0.1     |
|1  |04-03-2022 |0.2     |
|2  |05-03-2022 |0.1     |
|2  |05-03-2022 |0.2     |
|2  |04-03-2022 |0.1     |
|2  |04-03-2022 |0.2     |
|3  |05-03-2022 |0.1     |
|3  |05-03-2022 |0.2     |
|3  |04-03-2022 |0.1     |
|3  |04-03-2022 |0.2     |


Table 2 :

|ID |DDate     |   |Dversion|
 :-  :---------     :------
|1  |05-03-2022|   |  1     |
|1  |05-03-2022|   |  2     |
|1  |04-03-2022|   |  1     |
|1  |04-03-2022|   |  2     |
|2  |05-03-2022|   |  1     |
|2  |05-03-2022|   |  2     |
|2  |04-03-2022|   |  1     |
|2  |04-03-2022|   |  2     |


Output : 

|Table 1.ID |Table2.ID|        |Date       |
 :---------  :--------          :----------
|1          |1        |        | 05-03-2022|
|2          |2        |        | 05-03-2022|
|3          |NULL     |        | 05-03-2022|
```

Comment: Those are the table details pasted out in an excel. Table 1, Table 2 and output

Comment: Apologies if the right format is not followed. This is my first post here and will correct it going forward

Comment: @Anonymous47 Could you post your tables as text instead of a photograph? Also add your desired output. Thanks.

Comment: Have posted the table structure and the output expected as well.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Future, edit your existing post, and put actual sample data WITHIN your posted questions, not images.  As for the query, what you would be looking for is a LEFT JOIN.  Meaning, I want all records from a left-side (first table listed) regardless of a matching record on the right-side (second) based on whatever the common key.  That said, it would be something like

```
select
      t1.id,
      t1.id tbl2ID,
      t2.ddate
   from
      Table1 t1
         LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
            on t1.id = t2.id
           AND t1.tdate = t2.ddate
   where
      t1.tdate = '2022-05-03'
```

Again, not having your table structure listed, and going by a bad image which you could have done a print-screen even.  This should get what you are looking for.  Notice that Table1 is the left table (first one listed in the query) LEFT JOINed to the right table (second one) based on whatever the common ID between them.

The selected columns, just pull whatever the columns of interest are.  The "t1" and "t2" are just aliases vs writing what could be long table names repeatedly in longer and more complex queries.  Or even using the same table multiple times in the same query for different purposes / conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But the issue Im facing here is that for each ID there are multiple entries based on Date and the versin, so I need to filter out for a paticular date and version and then do a Join. Could you please help me in adding conditions based on the fields

Comment: @Anonymous47, see revised answer, as best as what you have provided and asked about.